# PHP Regex is truncating matches

Tags: php, regex

A little help needed.

I am part way there I think.

I have strings like this in a body of text :

"line: this is something or other with an escaped semi-colon here \; but I want to ignore that up to this final one;"

So in the middle of my string I want to include the escaped semi colon but not treat it as the end of the string - the end of the string should be the final semi-colon.

I have this regex pattern :

```
$regex = "/line:(.*?)[^\\\;];/";
```

Whilst it matches the pattern with this :

```
preg_match_all($regex, $texttosearch, $matches)
```

The contents of $matches[1][0] is truncated, in this example the 'e' is missing...

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => line: this is something or other with an escaped semi-colon here \; but I want to ignore that up to this final one;
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] =>  this is something or other with an escaped semi-colon here \; but I want to ignore that up to this final on
    )

 )
```

Could anyone help with where I am going wrong please ?

Thank you.

Comment: Can there be ``\\`` (escaped backslash)? What if there is `\\;`? Will it be the end of the match?

Comment: You aren't capturing the non `\;` before the `;`.

Comment: You are trying to get to [`line:(.*?)(?<!\\);`](https://regex101.com/r/pSxzQv/1), but is it really working in all cases? Try [`line:([^;\\]*(?:\\.[^;\\]*)*);`](https://regex101.com/r/pSxzQv/3)

Comment: Also see ^ because `[^\\;]` is not, non `\;`; it is non `;` or non `\` (< backslash in there). Character classes are allowed character(s) (or negated).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew No I only need escaped semicolons.

Comment: @chris85 Thanks, I didn't realise that. Will do some reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that just using a lookbehind to check if a `;` is not preceded with `\` is error-prone in case you may have other escape sequences. Use this unrolled regex (as a PHP single quoted string literal):

```
'~line:([^;\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^;\\\\]*)*);~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pSxzQv/3)

*Details*:

- `line:` - literal substring (to match it as a whole word, add `\b` in front of it)
- `([^;\\]*(?:\\.[^;\\]*)*)` - Group  1 capturing:

  - `[^;\\]*` - 0+ chars other than `;` and `\`
  - `(?:\\.[^;\\]*)*` - 0+ sequences of:

    - `\\.` - any escaped char (add `~s` modifier to allow `.` to match linebreaks, too)
    - `[^;\\]*`- 0+ chars other than `;` and `\`
- `;`  - a semi-colon

Comment: Yes that worked. Thanks for the assistance, much appreciated and much to learn.